# Travelling to Venice on All Saint's day

Tags: public-holidays, venice

I'm planning a 2 day visit to Venice and a good date for my family includes November 1st. Since this is the All Saint's day I'm wondering how big of a deal is it in Italy and more specifically in a touristy place like Venice.

Will anything be open? Shops, restaurants, museums? Will we be able to plan some sights?  With the kids we could take a boat ride on the canals, visit some Islands and of course just wonder around the city..

So anyway, how "closed" would Venice be on 1st of November?

Comment: I know officially All Saints day is a holiday in Italy (which I did search), but I also know that at tourist locations a holiday mostly means business as usual. Now Venice is not strictly a tourist place but it does have a lot of tourism. Hence my question: what can I expect to be open? Museums being open on a Sunday for example is pretty common on one hand, but All Saints Day can carry heavy familial obligations (it does so in my neighbouring, also predominantly Catholic country) so on the other hand everything might still be closed. A Venice (or Italian) local replying would be ideal.

Comment: Sadly no - I had to cancel our reservation because of extreme weather conditions. The city was flooded, sights were closed, vaporettos weren't operating and the Italian government advised against traveling unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Hope You can make this travel some day. Specially sharing it with your family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely will be a great trip, specially in family and great date as well to go!

The museums has an earlier leave times but remains open. The same probably would apply on some other places, depending on what are you interested to see. Check directly on the sites You are interested.

For example, on Doge's Palace Museum on Nov 1st the last admission is at 4:30pm. On normal days is 6:00pm

You can get great resources using the [Google Local Guides site](https://www.localguidesconnect.com/)

From there you can jump to other sites. [Like this tour on Venice](https://blog.headout.com/3-days-venice-itinerary/)

The important thing is to make a previous plan on your route accordingly to what You want to visit/watch/eat/see/experience. And research a little bit on official sites about costs and times.

Probably You can connect with some local guides using the Google site above.

Bon voyage!